# How to accept Integers or Strings JAVA

Tags: java

```
   private void CreateAccount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String firstName, accountType="";
        double initialDesposit = 0;                      
        boolean valid = false;
        int Current = 1;
        int Saving = 2;
        while (!valid){                    //Only can select current or saving account
            System.out.println("Enter account Type");
            System.out.println("1:Current");          
            System.out.println("2:Saving");
             accountType = keyboard.nextLine(); //User Input of the Account Type 


            if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Current") || accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Saving")|| accountType.equals(1) || accountType.equals(2) ){
                valid = true;  //If selection is true 
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }
```

I am trying to make it that when user is displayed option they can either choose the option by number or letters i.e. instead of typing "Saving" user can simply just press "2" and it is recorded as Saving.

Comment: String cant be equal with Integer , try this accountType.equals("1")  accountType.equals("2")

Comment: So, look for `accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Current") || accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("1")`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, what your question is, because your post doesn't contain one, however i think, you have at least one error in your if clause:

```
if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Current") || accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Saving")|| accountType.equals(1) || accountType.equals(2) )
```

Since `accountType` is a String, comparing it with an integer number will always fail. You could write it like following to compare it with strings:

```
if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Current") || accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Saving")|| accountType.equals("1") || accountType.equals("2") )
```

This should work, because you get strings as input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Scanner` class:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = "";

if (sc.hasNext()) {
    userInput = sc.next();
}

if (userInput.equals("Current") || userInput.equals("1")) {
    // option 1
} else if (userInput.equals("Saving") || userInput.equals("2")) {
    // option 2
} else {
    // bad or no input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void CreateAccount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String firstName, accountType="";
        double initialDesposit = 0;                      
        boolean valid = false;
        int Current = 1;
        int Saving = 2;
        while (!valid){                    //Only can select current or saving account
            System.out.println("Enter account Type");
            System.out.println("1:Current");          
            System.out.println("2:Saving");
             accountType = keyboard.nextLine(); //User Input of the Account Type 


            if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Current") || accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Saving")|| accountType.equals("1") || accountType.equals("2") ){
                valid = true;  //If selection is true 
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
private void CreateAccount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String firstName, accountType = "";
    double initialDesposit = 0;
    boolean valid = false;
    int Current = 1;
    int Saving = 2;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isInt = false;
    while (!valid) {                    //Only can select current or saving account
        System.out.println("Enter account Type");
        System.out.println("1:Current");
        System.out.println("2:Saving");
        accountType = sc.nextLine(); //User Input of the Account Type 

        isInt = isInteger(accountType);

        if (isInt) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(accountType) == 1 || Integer.parseInt(accountType) == 2) {
                valid = true;  //If selection is true 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        } else {
            if (accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Current") || accountType.equalsIgnoreCase("Saving")) {
                valid = true;  //If selection is true 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }

    }
}

public boolean isInteger(String check) {
    for (int i = 0; i < check.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(check.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void CreateAccount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String firstName, ="";
        int accountType = 0;
        double initialDesposit = 0;                      
        boolean valid = false;
        int Current = 1;
        int Saving = 2;
        while (!valid){                    //Only can select current or saving account
            System.out.println("Enter account Type");
            System.out.println("1:Current");          
            System.out.println("2:Saving");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             accountType = sc.nextInt(); //User Input of the Account Type 


            if (accountType == 1 || accountType == 2){
                valid = true;  //If selection is true 
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid");
            }
        }
```

Comment: From OP's question "choose the option by number or letters"

Comment: Simply place the numbers in quotes then as the type is String... Geesh

Comment: Nope. That's not how you compare Strings in Java.

Comment: See Dunni's answer mate